# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate:

> $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}$$

Comment: @Yigeng You have asked $9$ questions so far. It is time to start accepting some of the answers to your other questions.

Comment: @Marvis: I agree with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Showing that $\int\limits_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{x}} \mathrm dx = \int\limits_0^a f(x) \mathrm dx$, when $f$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/showing-that-int-limits-aa-fracfx1ex-mathrm-dx-int-limits-0)

From the above, we get that
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \dfrac{dx}{(1+e^x)(1+x^2)} = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)} = \arctan(x) \left. \right\vert_{x=0}^{1} = \dfrac{\pi}4$$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal The existence of the integral is pretty obvious. The integrand is a nice function bounded above by $1$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: What do you mean?

Comment: @Marivis: Sorry. I was looking at the wrong integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(e^x-1)(x^2+1)}\,.$

Comment: @Marvis: indeed; the even part of $\frac1{1+e^x}$ is $\frac12$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Since the even part of $\frac1{e^x-1}$ is $-\frac12$, the Cauchy Principal Value of your integral would be $-\frac\pi4$.