# How to calculate $\int_{-a}^{a} [f'(x)\log(1+e^x)\,]dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The complete problem says: Let $f(x) \in C^1 [-a,a]$ and even, calculate

$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^{a} \left[\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x} + f'(x)\log(1+e^x) \right]dx$

The first part is [easy to see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/showing-that-int-limits-aa-fracfx1ex-mathrm-dx-int-limits-0?lq=1).

I don't know how to use the hypothesis that $f'(x)$ is continuous. I used that if $f(x)$ is even $f'(x)$ is odd, but this lead me that $\int_{-a}^{a}f'(x) = 0$...

Comment: Actually you don't need to emphasize this is homework.

Comment: If $f$ supposed to be even, and if so, perhaps you should mention it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a little integration by parts?

$$u=\log(1+e^x)\;,\;\;\;u'=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}=1-\frac{1}{1+e^x}\\v'=f'(x)\;,\;\;v=f(x)$$

$$\left.\int\limits_{-a}^af'(x)\log(1+e^x)\,dx=f(x)\log(1+e^x)\right|_{-a}^a-\int_{-a}^a\left(f(x)-\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}\right)dx=$$

$$=f(a)\overbrace{\left(\log\frac{1+e^a}{1+e^{-a}}\right)}^{\color{red}{\text{this equals}\; a}}+\int\limits_0^af(x)\,dx$$

using the result you linked to and, of course, the fact that the integral of an even (integrable) function on a symmetric interval is zero

Comment: Ach! Was just in the middle of typing this! The $\log$ at the end simplifies to $a$ of course.

Comment: Good catch on that log thing, L.F. I was so concentrated on *the other* part of the equation that I didn't even pay attention to that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!. I still having problems with integrations by parts.

Comment: @David, do you mean you have problems with that method or with the particular integration by parts shown in the answer? By parts is one of the most basic and useful integration techniques, and I assumed you already know it well if you're dealing with this kind of problems.

Comment: Yes, I know how integrate by parts, but when use it?... is my problem.

Comment: Then, the integral is $a f(a) + \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx$

Comment: @David, that is *everybody's* problem. I guess we all must develop an intuition on this. There is no pre-cooked formula that tells us when to use this or that method on integrating *in each and every case*, though there are many cases that beg this or that method. Practice, practice and more practice.

Comment: The integral from the beginning in fact is $$af(a)+2\int\limits_0^a f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Well, but $2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx$ when $f(x)$ is even?

Comment: Of course, @David, you're right.