# find the value of ${\int_{0}}^1 (1+e^{-x^2})dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to find 
$${\int_{0}}^1 (1+e^{-x^2})dx$$

How do I integrate $e^{-x^2}$  it can't be done by parts.

Comment: See if http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/showing-that-int-limits-aa-fracfx1ex-mathrm-dx-int-limits-0 is helpful

Answer (score 4):

$e^{-x^2}$ cannot be integrated in terms of elementary functions, so a numerical approach is suggested. Alternatively, consider the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: Another alternative is to use the series expansion of $e^{-x^2}$ and to integrate term by term.