# Anybody to solve this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can someone help me with this definite integral? 
$$ \int _{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1}{1+2^x}  dx $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Basically every elementary method, plugged it in a solver but it couldn't find it either,

Comment: hint: the answer is a pretty well known irrational number

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741580/integral-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac12007x1-cdot-frac-sin2008x-si/741698#741698

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771320/evaluate-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac-cosx1ex-dx/771323#771323

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/showing-that-int-limits-aa-fracfx1ex-mathrm-dx-int-limits-0

Answer (score 10):

Split the integral into two parts:
$$I = \int _{-\pi}^{0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1}{1+2^x}  dx + \int _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1}{1+2^x}  dx$$

Applying the substitution $x \to -x$ on the first integral:
$$I = \int _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1}{1+2^{-x}}  dx + \int _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1}{1+2^x}  dx$$
Multiply top and bottom of first integral by $2^x$:
$$I = \int _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{2^x}{1+2^x}  dx + \int _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1}{1+2^x}  dx$$
Sum the two integrals:
$$I= \int _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)} dx$$
Use the fact that $\sin(3x) = 3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$ by the triple-angle formula:
$$I= \int _{0}^{\pi}3-4\sin^2(x) dx$$
Using the fact that $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(x)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}:$
$$I = 3\pi-4\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \pi$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!